# How to hide export variable details shell script

Tags: shell

I have 2 script

script 1 : demo_details.txt

script 2 : demo.sh

Script 1 : Path : /demo/d/demo_details.txt and contain below details

```
export CON_DB_TECY=Username/Password@host:port/Servicename -> `abc/abc@local:123/orabc`
```

Script 2 : Path : /demo/d/demo.sh and contain below code

```
. /demo/d/demo_details.txt
 
    sqlplus -s -S << EOF
    $CON_DB_TECY
      select * from dual;
      exit;
    EOF
```

When i run above script 2 using ->  `sh x demo.sh`
It prints details of demo_details.txt => `CON_DB_TECY=abc/abc@local:123/orabc`

which is connection details that i want to secure and
should not be displayed when i run script using `sh -x demo.sh`

Answer (score 0):

you can put all connection and sql in demo_details.txt and redirect it
demo_details.txt

```
Username/Password.....
select * from dual;
exit;
```

then
demo.sh

```
sqlplus -s -S <demo_details.txt
```